# User configs are removed from 70-snap.core.rules file under certain conditions in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: usb, ubuntu-18.04, udev

I have a modem which has a USB serial port connection. When I connect this modem to PC, I usually have 4 ttyUSB ports as ttyUSB1, ttyUSB2, ttyUSB3, ttyUSB4 and I can work with these ports in my C++ program. But sometimes these port names change to ttyUSB5 or 6 or 7 or ... and I want to use static names for my modem ports based on idProduct and idVendor of the modem.

So, I use the following commands at the end of the 70-snap.core.rules file in /etc/udev/rules.d to use always static names:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="90CA", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0071", ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}=="00", SYMLINK+="static_port0"
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="90CA", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0071", ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}=="01", SYMLINK+="static_port1"
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="90CA", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0071", ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}=="02", SYMLINK+="static_port2"
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="90CA", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0071", ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}=="03", SYMLINK+="static_port3"
```

But I think that this file will be recreated under certain conditions in Ubuntu, because sometimes my static names do not work and my configs is removed from 70-snap.core.rules file.

Is there a permanently file to use permanently static names for my USB ports in Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve the problem by creating an empty file in the /etc/udev/rules.d folder and inserting my configs into it. This file will not be recreated automatically. So after restarting, I can see the permanently static names for my USB ports.